# Indirect(Address(....'Name' issue

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a range named 'select' which contains random numbers `=ROUND(RAND()*8+0.5,0)` - These represent 8 people. Elsewhere I use the following formula to randomly select from those random numbers.

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(select),ROW(select)+ROWS(select)-1),RANDBETWEEN(COLUMN(select),COLUMN(select)+COLUMNS(select)-1)))
```

This works fine **only** in the worksheet 'select' was defined in. It won't work in other sheets in the workbook.'Select' is set for use in the workbook.  What am I missing?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but why don't you just use `RANDBETWEEN(1,8)` to generate the numbers between 1 and 8?

Answer (score 0):

You’re calling `ADDRESS(n, m)`,
where *`n`* is a (random) row number and *`m`* is a column number. 
The `ADDRESS()` function sees only those two numbers;
it doesn’t see that they’re coming from `ROW(select)` and `COLUMN(select)`;
so it just generates an address string like `$Q$42`;
it doesn’t know to qualify it with the sheet where `select` is. 
You need to change your `ADDRESS` call to something like

```
ADDRESS((row_number), (column_number),,, (sheet_name))
```

e.g.,

```
ADDRESS(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(select),ROW(select)+ROWS(select)-1),RANDBETWEEN(COLUMN(select),COLUMN(select)+COLUMNS(select)-1),,, "Sheet2")
```

if `select` is on `Sheet2`.